# How to extend the pandas' Dataframe class with my own methods and functions

Tags: python, pandas, class, inheritance, dataframe

**First question:**

I am working with pandas' DataFrames and I am frequently running the same routines as part of data pre-processing and other things. I'd like to write some of these routines as methods in a class called `ExtendedDataframe` that extends `pandas.DataFrame`. I don't know how to go about this. So far, I'm not writing any `__init__` in my new class so that it's inherited from `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
import pandas
class ExtendedDataframe(pandas.DataFrame):
  def some_method(self):
    blahblah
```

This apparently enables me to create an instance of `ExtendedDataframe` by inheritance. But I'm usually loading data through something like `pandas.read_csv` which returns a classic `DataFrame`. How can I do to be able to load such csv data and at some point turn it into an `ExtendedDataframe` to use my own methods, on top of those provided on standard `DataFrame`? It's fine if the loading phase returns a standard `DataFrame` that I then transform into an `ExtendedDataframe`.

**Second question:**

Not all pandas' functionalities that I use are DataFrame methods. Some are functions, such as `pandas.merge`, that take DataFrames as arguments. How can I extend the use of such functions to instances of my `ExtendedDataframe` class? In otherwords, if `df1` and `df2` are two instances of `ExtendedDataframe`, how do I make

```
pandas.merge([df1, df2], ...)
```

work just like it would with standard instances of `DataFrame`?

Answer (score 8):

This doesn't directly answer your question but it is a potential answer to your problem. Lot's of people use the pipe method in their workflows.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html

Instead of saying

```
df = foo(df)
```

you can say

```
df = df.pipe(foo)
```

You can even specify arguments for the function! This will be much easier to maintain than trying to encapsulate the whole dataframe class. So the idea is that you can just create a library of functions and pipe them as needed.

Comment: That's indeed a possible solution, thanks! Is there otherwise a good general way to simply add methods/attributes to a built-in class?

Comment: The issue that you'll run into is that as soon as you invoke a built in method it will return a normal DataFrame not your custom one.

Comment: Ok so the only solution would be to modify the built-in class itself (which I don't think I want to do)?

Comment: You definitely don't want to do that. I mean saying pipe and then calling the function you want will be more sustainable in the long run. That's been my solution for the last year and I haven't found any problems with it.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem today, with a colleagues help I found out that this works:

```
import pandas as pd

class MyDF(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyDF,  self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return MyDF

    def my_custom_method(self):
        print('This actually works!')
```

Example:

```
df = MyDF(columns=('a', 'b'))
df = df.append({'a': 1, 'b': 'test'})
print(df)
df.my_custom_method()  # prints "This actually works!"
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure in which version of Pandas decorators for extending DataFrame, etc. were introduced. You can read more about it on the following address: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html

Answer (score 0):

When you create instance of your dataframe, they are DataFrame object. You can modify existing methods overriding them in this way ____existingMethod____ 
About the second questions, I would suggest you to create a new class in which you pass the 2 dataframes. In this case you will have to  make the ____init____ method

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the constructor like this:

```
import pandas
from datetime import datetime

class ExtendedDataframe(pandas.DataFrame):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    pandas.DataFrame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.created_at = datetime.today()

  def to_csv(self, *args, **kwargs):
    copy = self.copy()
    copy["created_at"] = self.created_at
    pd.DataFrame.to_csv(copy, *args, **kwargs)
```